# showing progress bar on my application

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am very new to windows programming, I have a windows application, that on the click of the button, it calls the web service and
 gets the data from the web service and then inserts the value to the database. I need to show the progeress bar for all this. below is my code

```
private void btnService_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //call to the web service
        //get the data
        //insert the returned data from web service to the database.   
}
```

I put the progress bar control on my page, but it seems to me that I have to assign some number to the progress bar so that it shows the status.

Comment: This cannot work, you have no idea how long the service will take.  Set the progress bar's Style property to Marquee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using a block progress bar, you can update its status like this

```
int totalSteps = 10;
for (int i= 1; i<= totalSteps; i++)
{
    //  One chunk of your code

    int progress = i * 100 / totalSteps;
    blocksProgressBar.Value = progress;
}
blocksProgressBar.Value = 0;
```

If you use a background worker, the bar may be updated like this

```
private void btnService_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int totalSteps = 10;

    for (int i = 1; i <= totalSteps; i++)
    {
        //  One chunk of your code

        int progress = i * 100 / totalSteps;
        backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(progress);
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    blocksProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void backgroundWorker_Completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    blocksProgressBar.Value = 0;
}
```

[Source](http://mycodelog.com/2010/02/11/busy/)